# QAF weird behavior for parallel testing

Tags: cucumber, browserstack, parallel-testing, qaf

for example:

**testing.xml**

```
<suite name="name" parallel="methods" thread-count="5"> 
   <test>
     ...
   </test>
 </suite>
```

**case #1:** when I run the following feature file with @smoke tag per say, it will execute parallel testing normally:

**something1.feature**

```
@smoke
Feature: <feature message>
   Scenario: <scenario1 message> 
        ...
   Scenario: <scenario2 message>
```

**case#2:** when I execute the same scenario using 'Scenario Outlines' is when parallel testing goes concurrently even though the parallel testing configuration is setup in the TestNG xml file.

**something2.feature**

```
Feature: <feature message> 
   Scenario Outline: <scenario outline messsage> 
        ... 
      Examples: 
         <data table>
```

does anybody knows why is this happening with QMETRY framework?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using TestNG, `Scenario Outline` is converted to TestNG data-driven tests. In TestNG there is separate mechanism for data driven test case parallel execution. QAF provides property `global.datadriven.parallel` to set parallel behavior for data driven tests. Default value is `false`. Make sure that you have set it to true in order to run data-driven tests in parallel.

```
global.datadriven.parallel=true
```